# How to center text veritically and horizontally inside a css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to center some text inside a grid container, but  the closest I have managed is   what I created on the snippet, but my text appears almost as if it was nested, and I will like all of it to be centered, like the columns of a newspaper/magazine ?

I don't know if I'm explaining this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="item">Content 1 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum Content 1 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum Content 1 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum</p>
  <p class="item"> Content 2 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum Content 2 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum</p>
  <p class="item"> Content 3 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In what was is this NOT working? What is this **supposed** to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that multiple text lines to have equal length, then it is possible to use `text-align: justify;` or `text-align: justify-all;`.

[As mdn says about](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) `text-align: justify;`:

> **justify:** The inline contents are justified. Text should be spaced to
> line up its left and right edges to the left and right edges of the
> line box, except for the last line.

and `text-align: justify-all;`:

> Same as justify, but also forces the last line to be
> justified.

An exampple:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="item">Content 1 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum Content 1 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum Content 1 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum</p>
    <p class="item"> Content 2 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum Content 2 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum</p>
    <p class="item"> Content 3 lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum lorem ipsulum</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to use flexbox :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```